# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am using Quickblox framework for storing and retrieving data in objective c project. Due to this framework `symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` problem occur . I am not using CocoaPods.I have tried lot of solutions form stackoverflow.Please help me for solving this issue.  [problem snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51rsD.png)

Comment: Did you add the lib  libxml2 by adding the flag: `-lxml2` and modifying the header path? http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#Manual_installation That's what make me think of the "_xmlStrQEqual" issue For the _dns_stuff, my first thought would go the to `CFNetwork.framework` not added. So what did you do exactly?

Comment: Yes i have added `libxml2` with `-lxml2`

Comment: `x86_64` means you're trying to run it on the simulator. (Your mac has an x86 structure) Try it on an actual iOS device and report back.

Comment: if i follow :[link] (http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework) then it produce this error.
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_dns_free_resource_record", referenced from:
      l023 in Quickblox(XMPPSRVResolver.o)
  "_dns_parse_resource_record", referenced from:
      l023 in Quickblox(XMPPSRVResolver.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)